# How to redirect to other vhost in nginx

Tags: nginx, vhosts

Let's say I have `a.mywebsite.com` and `b.mywebsite.com`. Because the fully-qualified domain name could be something different e.g. in development and test environments it won't be `mywebsite.com`, I would like to make rules so that all requests to `a.` are moved to `b.`.

I presume that the configuration file could look something like the following, but I can't figure out what's the right thing to put int `<what goes here>`.

```
server {
  server_name ~^a\.;
  return 301 b.<what goes here?>;
}

server {
  server_name ~^b\.;
}
```

Or am I going totally the wrong direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a named regex group, e.g.:

```
server {
  server_name ~^a\.(?<domain>.+)$;
  return 301 b.$domain;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I suppose this becomes inefficient because regular expressions are slower to match though, right?

Comment: True, regular expressions are slower than exact match, but the original question already used regular expression anyway. I believe it's not much trouble to have it on a redirect uri, since we direct clients to go away from that address. In target vhost `~^b\.` regex could be replaced with `b.*` which should be a little bit faster according to documentation (no regex; resolved through hash table).

Comment: I see. I think in the end, I'll try to make the nginx configuration files be rendered templates, so that they be both flexible and performant (hope I'm not going into premature optimization!)

Answer (score -1):

It is the simple solution to your requirement.

what goes here = mywebsite.com